# How to create a UIPickerView over UITabbar Controller?

Tags: iphone

In my app I have a `UITabBarController`.In one `UIViewController` I want to have a `UIPickerView`.I added this pickerview in the .`xib` file itself by adding it in separate view and keeping it out of frame until user taps the button.when the user taps the button,I unhidden this view and set a animation like keyboard.But my problem is, when the `UIPickerView` comes,it is coming under the `UITabBarController` ie.,tabbar controller is hiding half of the `UIPickerView`.I want to keep my `UIPickerView` over that `UITabBarController`.How can I do this.Please help.

Thanks u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you add pickerView(I think it's in your `UIViewController`)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [self.view addSubview:self.pickerView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pickerView];
    ...
}
```

Comment: But I added my picker view in xib.Just i bringing my picker view by unhiding the pickerview in the button action.Can u pls tell me where should I use ur code.my UIPickeView name is "selectPicker" and view name containing that UIPicker is "selectPickerView"