# Make UIPickerView in front of Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uitabbar

[image]

as you can see, my UIPickerView is in back a Tab bar, how to make it in front them? i'm using swift

and also my done button doesn't work to hide the UIView that contain UIPickerView, i'm sure the button connected to an action

here's my doneButton action

```
@IBAction func doneButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.viewUIPickerView.viewWithTag(1)?.hidden = true

}
```

Comment: Please look [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13193277/3116236) Hope this help

Comment: I think this may help you. kindly refer this link, [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252664/hide-the-tab-bar-in-a-tab-bar-application)

Comment: This may help you, refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252664/hide-the-tab-bar-in-a-tab-bar-application

Comment: This may help you, refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252664/hide-the-tab-bar-in-a-tab-bar-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When evere you try to open picker simply hide the tabbar like this

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true
```

onClick of done show the tabbar agian

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! I feel so stupid didn't realize it. But for some reason my done button doesn't perform an action, i'm pretty sure it's connected to the outlet

Comment: `@IBAction func doneButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.viewUIPickerView.viewWithTag(1)?.hidden = true
        self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = false
    }`

Comment: Please edit your question and add some code of done button click and pickerview.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1> you are open pickerview that uitabbar hidden and pickerview hidden that uitabbar show. For Example:

```
if (pickerview.hidden == true)
   self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false
else
   self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true
```

or

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = !pickerview.hidden
```

Solution 2> set your pickerview frame perfect:(for example)

```
self.pickerview.frame = CGRectMake(0,[UIScreen MainScreen].bound.size.height - self.pickerview.frame.size.height,self.pickerview.frame.size.width,self.pickerview.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of UITabBar on top of your ViewController. You can do one of following:

1. Hide Tabbar.
2. Add pickerView as subView of tabbar
3. Add pickerView on top of tabbar.

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

//Navigation bar:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

//Statusbar:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

//Tabbar:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```